# Vue getters cannot get integer parameter changes

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to vue. I want to catch the int parameter's changes like this:

```
volume.js:

const localSet = {
  state: {
    volume:1
  },
  getters: {
    volumeGetter: (state) => {
      return state.volume;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateVolume(state, devices) {
       if (devices && devices !== null) {
        if(!!devices.body) {
          devices = devices.body;
        }
        state.volume= devices.volume;
      }
    }
  },
  actions: {
    handleVolume({ state, commit }, params) {
      commit('updateVolume', params);
    },
}


vloume.vue:
  ...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['volumeGetter'])
  },
  watch: {
    volumeGetter: {
      deep: true,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.inputVolume = newValue; //never called
      }
    }
  }
```

the result from server is a json like
`{"head":{"eventid":"getvolume"},"body":{"volume":0}}`

after receiving frome the server, `updateVolume` will set `state.volume` to `json.body.volume`. But the `volumeGetter` function doesn't run.

And I found that if I change `state.volume` from `int` to `json` like:

```
 ...
 state: {
    volume:{}
  },
 ...
```

the `volumeGetter` will run after recving message from server.

Does `getter` function in VUE cannot catch the changes of a Integer parameter?

Comment: Could you please share your full code for easy debugging?

Comment: How and where are you calling `volumeGetter` function?

Comment: @NehaSoni I set `computed{ ...mapGetters["volumeGetter"]}` and `watch:{volumeGetter{...}}`

Comment: Your code is working fine, can't see any issues. See the demo here- https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-store-forked-m229tb?file=/src/store.js

Comment: Try setting it integer, it is working in that case too.